# Background always move while making it responsive

Tags: css

So I have a background image that you can see on this image it is centered
[image]

But when I try to make it responsive this happens to the image
[image]

And I want it to not move and I've tried a lot of things like  `position: fixed` or changing the margin but nothing happens and the image always does this.

Here's the CSS code:

```
body{
    padding-left:14.12%;
    padding-right:14.12%;
    background-color:#000;
    margin: 0; 
    background-image: url(images/principal.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And here's the CSS code to make it responsive:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 321px){

    body{
        background-position: top center;
        background-position-x: -42%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `background-attachment: fixed` to `body {..}`

Comment: that doesn't work because now the image is just following the scroll

Comment: Then post your code (maybe runtime in Codepen), as that's the standard way to *fix* an image in place. Something else must be wrong... Check 'Try it Yourself' on this page [CSS background-attachment Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

Comment: try `background-size: cover;`

Comment: You can definitely trim down your CSS file very easy. You don't need three separate lines of CSS for all those background instructions, one line will do it `background: url(images/principal.jpg) top center no-repeat;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the image background in a DIV not in the body element, maybe in a header tag and set the height for the header.

HTML:

> ```
> <body>  
> <header></header> 
> </body>
> ```

CSS:

> ```
> header {
>  height: 100vh;
>  width: 100%;
>
>  background-image: url(images/principal.jpg);
>  background-position: center;
>  background-repeat: no-repeat;
>  background-size: cover;
> }
> ```

100vh means that the header will be always on screen size height resolution (mobile, desktop).
Also you can use @media and change the image on different resolutions.

Comment: I did what you said, put the image in the header tag, and add the background-sizer: cover; and the 100vh and problem was solved, thank you!